# How Can I subtract number from mysql table to finish in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have table named tb_product with three columns ProductID, Quantity and Price
if for example Product with ID 5 has a quantity of 20 and somebody bought one item out of it it should be remaining 19 items from the table. That is anytime an order is made product quantity should be subtracted by the number ordered till the product reaches 0 or finishes from the product table.
I have no idea about the it, please somebody help me.

Comment: The command you are looking for is `UPDATE` but you need to make sure your code handles multiple users at the same time. ie, before running the update to reduce the value, check the current value first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
update tb_product set quantity=quantity-1 where productid=productid
```

Comment: How about bought product and 0 stock limit?

Comment: update tb_product set quantity=quantity-1 where productid=productid and quantity>0

Comment: 0 stock means product not in stock

Comment: update tb_product set quantity=quantity-1 where productid=productid and quantity>0

Above query will not update quantity if product is out of stock i.e. 0

Comment: Rahul Chauhan, Your observer was very helpful

Answer (score 0):

My question was partially answered by Raphul Chauham, because his answer does not give me exactly what i was looking for but subtracted the quantity column by 1 instead of by the variable representative from the order. Below is what I wanted exactly.

```
<?php
$updateProduct=mysql_query("UPDATE tb_products SET quantity=quantity-'$quantity' WHERE productID='$product_id' and quantity>0");
?>
```

The answer I considered favorable was only subtracting quantity by one whether order quantity is 20 but with this, the subtraction vary as user order varies by the variable `$quantity`